# Adding custom property to JSON creates duplicate

Tags: javascript, json

I am adding a custom property to my JSON, but at the end it creates a duplicate! One containing my custom property name and another without it.

```
var array = [];
array.push([]);
var parentKey = "HELLO";
array[array.length - 1].push(array[array.length - 1].parent = parentKey);
console.log(array);
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/12d69z34/)

So in the end I want to get:

```
[
    [
            "Parent": "Hello"
    ]
]
```

Comment: Show results that you want to get?

Comment: So are you trying to add an object to an array, so you end up with `[{"say" : "HELLO"}]`

Comment: That isn't JSON. It is just javascript arrays and objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your  code :

```
array = [[]]
array[array.length - 1].push(array[array.length - 1].parent = parentKey);
```

creates the following object :

```
[ [ 'HELLO', parent: 'HELLO' ] ]
```

However, the **problem** is you are **using push() with an assignment** as parameter, which executes the assignment and then adds the return value of the assignment (which is the property) to the array, that's the reason for the duplicate you are seeing.

The right way to create the JSON object is :

```
array = [[]]
array[array.length - 1].parent = parentKey;
```

which gives :

```
[ [ parent: 'HELLO' ] ]
```

**NOTE**:

As also pointed by Juhana below, (not knowing your usage context) if you want to create an array of JSON objects, then the following is the most correct one :

```
array = [{}]
array[array.length - 1].parent = parentKey;
```

Comment: You're using an array when you should use an object. It should be `array=[{}]`.

Answer (score 3):

`array[array.length - 1].push(array[array.length - 1].parent = parentKey);`

The `(array[array.length - 1].parent = parentKey)` doesn't return that `array[array.length - 1]`, instead, it returns `parentKey`.

So

```
array[array.length - 1].push(array[array.length - 1].parent = parentKey);
```

is equal to

```
var item = array[array.length - 1].parent = parentKey; // item becomes "HELLO" here
array[array.length - 1].push(item);
```

So you just assign Assign a property `parent` with `"HELLO"` to `array[array.length - 1]`, and then push "Hello" to `array[array.length - 1]`.

That's not a duplicate.

And to what you expect, you should write:

```
var array = [];
array.push({});  // Push object to here
var parentKey = "HELLO";
array[array.length - 1].parent = parentKey;
console.log(array);
```